# How to replace multiple characters with different input on same string python

Tags: python, string, replace

I am attempting to replace multiple letters within a string, I want the vowels to be replaced by the users input, and my current code replaces all the vowels with the same letters, however I want to replace the vowels with different user inputs. Below is an example of what I would like, and the code below that.

What I want

```
input1 = zz
input2 = xx
input3 = yolo

output = yzzlxx
```

What I have

```
input1 = zz
input2 = xx
input3 = yolo

output = yzzlzz
```

Here is my code.

```
def vwl():
    syl1 = input("Enter your first syllable: ")
    syl2 = input("Enter the second syllable: ")
    translate = input("Enter word to replace vowels in: ")

    for ch in ['a','e','i','o','u']:
        if ch in translate:
            translate=translate.replace(ch,syl1,)

    for ch in ['a','e','i','o','u']:
        if syl1 in translate:
            translate=translate.replace(ch,syl2,)

    print (translate)
```

Comment: Ryan: Is this a homework question that you are doing? If so, please use the "homework" tag.

Comment: @MarkHildreth: actually, the `homework` tag has recently been deprecated.  See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated).

Comment: What determines which inputs replace which vowels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method [`replace`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) takes an additional argument `count`:

```
translate=translate.replace(ch,syl1,1)
break # finish the for loop for syl1
```

will only replace the first instance of ch and break will ensure you don't replace any subsequent vowels with `syl1`.

Similarly:

```
translate=translate.replace(ch,syl2,1)
break # finish the for loop
```

Comment: This doesn't help if the user inputs `yoli` (he'll still get `yxxlxx`).

Comment: it's a bit weird of a requirement ... (using `count` on `str.replace` was my first intuition as well)

Comment: Yes, I think that does it.  (I'm glad you didn't delete your answer.  I like to avoid `re` when possible) (+1).

Answer (score 3):

You can use regular expressions:

```
translate = re.sub('a|e|i|o|u',input1,translate,count=1)
translate = re.sub('a|e|i|o|u',input2,translate,count=1)
```

Example:

```
>>> input1 = 'zz'
>>> input2 = 'xx'
>>> translate = 'yolo'
>>> import re
>>> translate = re.sub('a|e|i|o|u',input1,translate,count=1)
>>> translate
'yzzlo'
>>> translate = re.sub('a|e|i|o|u',input2,translate,count=1)
>>> translate
'yzzlxx'
```